# Reshape objects using groupby

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array of objects:

```
    const data=[
        {
            "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z",
            "Benzene": 3.6
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z",
            "O3": 3.7
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z",
            "PM10": 3.1
        },
    
       {
            "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z",
            "Benzene": 2.6
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z",
            "O3": 5.7
        },
        {
            "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z",
            "PM10": 10.5
       

 }
]
```

I want to reshape it by grouping by Date only as follow:

```
[{ "date":"2020-01-30",
   "values":[{"t":"2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z",
              "Benzene":3.6,
              "O3":3.7,
              "PM10":3.1}]},
{ "date":"2020-03-30",
   "values":[{"t":"2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z",
              "Benzene":2.6,
              "O3":5.7,
              "PM10":10.5}]}]
```

I suppose that I can accomplish this using Loadash and `.map`, but I can't figure it how.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) first from lodash to group elements by their `datetime` and then apply [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to both map and combine values of each group elements.
A possible approach could be as below

```js
const data = [{
    "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z",
    "Benzene": 3.6
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z",
    "O3": 3.7
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z",
    "PM10": 3.1
  },

  {
    "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z",
    "Benzene": 2.6
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z",
    "O3": 5.7
  },
  {
    "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z",
    "PM10": 10.5
  }
];

const groups = _.groupBy(data, i => i['datetime'].substring(0, 10));

const res = Object.entries(groups).reduce((acc, g) => {
  const [key, values] = g;
  acc.push({
    date: key,
    values: [Object.assign({}, ...values)]
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-compat/3.10.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine. Could you suggest me some useful article/tutorial regarding JSON/data manipulation?

Comment: @EanX It's good to know that it works for you. I can share my learning materials with you, hope those will help you 
1. [You Don't Know JS: ES6 & Beyond - kyle simpson (A fanboy of ydkjs)](https://www.amazon.com/You-Dont-Know-JS-Beyond/dp/1491904240)
2. [How to Use Map, Filter, & Reduce in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-map-reduce-and-filter-explained-with-examples/)
3. [Functional Programming in JS: What? Why? How?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtsbZarFzm8)
4. [Functional Programming Fundamentals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkRyjXDpYqg)

Comment: Thanks @ParthoShuvo, it works fine for the provided data but not for my real case. Please check my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634294/reshape-json-using-lodash-and-reduce). I can't understand why it works for one item only, i.e. I want to gather all reads for all hours for a specific date inside "values" key but I get only one hour (one item).

Comment: the expected output should be: [{
        "date": "2020-06-30",
        "values": [
            {
                "t": "2020-06-30T00:59:59.000Z",
                "Benzene": 5.5,
                "NO2": 11.7,
                "O3": 35.1
            },   {
                "t": "2020-06-30T01:59:59.000Z",
                "Benzene": 5.2,
                "NO2": 15.7,
                "O3": 55.7
            }
        ]
    }
] With multiple objects inside the same date but one for every hour that gathers all sensors readings. Instead, I obtain only the last hour reading.

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact desired output, try:

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const find = acc.find(el => el.date === val.datetime.substring(0, 10));
    const { datetime, ...obj } = val;

    if (find) {
        find.values[0] = { ...find.values[0], ...obj };
    } else {
        acc.push({ date: datetime.substring(0, 10), values: [{ t: datetime, ...obj }] });
    }

    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: I followed your approach but it works for one item only, please check my code/post at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634294/reshape-json-using-lodash-and-reduce)

Comment: In this new [post](http://cemec.arpacampania.it/meteoambientecampania/php/downloadFileDati.php?path=/var/www/html/meteoambientecampania/prodotti/aria/arpac_dati_centraline_20200630.csv) I try to better clarify my problem and the solution I was able to code. Could you suggest a better approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `javascript` without `lodash`, like other answers, here is my try with reduce:

```js
var data=[ { "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z", "Benzene": 3.6 }, { "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z", "O3": 3.7 }, { "datetime": "2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z", "PM10": 3.1 }, { "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z", "Benzene": 2.6 }, { "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z", "O3": 5.7 }, { "datetime": "2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z", "PM10": 10.5 }];

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,{datetime, ...rest})=>{
    const date = datetime.slice(0,10)
    acc[date] = acc[date] || {date, values:[]};
    acc[date].values = [{...acc[date].values[0], ...{t:datetime, ...rest}}];
    return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It works for a single row of values inside a specific date.

Comment: Thanks @gorak, it works fine for the provided data but not for my real case. Please check my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62634294/reshape-json-using-lodash-and-reduce).  I can't understand why it works for one item only, i.e. I want to gather all reads for all hours for a specific date inside a values field but I get only one hour.

Comment: In this new [post](http://cemec.arpacampania.it/meteoambientecampania/php/downloadFileDati.php?path=/var/www/html/meteoambientecampania/prodotti/aria/arpac_dati_centraline_20200630.csv) I try to better clarify my problem and the solution I was able to code. Could you suggest a better approach? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead

```js
const data = [
    {
        datetime: '2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        Benzene: 3.6,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        O3: 3.7,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        PM10: 3.1,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        Benzene: 2.6,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        O3: 5.7,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        PM10: 10.5,
    },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const tryFind = acc.find(el => el.date === val.datetime);
    const { datetime, ...valExcludeDate } = val;

    if (tryFind) {
        tryFind.values[0] = { ...tryFind.values[0], ...valExcludeDate };
    } else {
        acc.push({ date: datetime, values: [{ ...valExcludeDate }] });
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

but I think object as a result will suit you more

```js
const data = [
    {
        datetime: '2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        Benzene: 3.6,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        O3: 3.7,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-01-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        PM10: 3.1,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        Benzene: 2.6,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        O3: 5.7,
    },
    {
        datetime: '2020-03-30T00:59:59.000Z',
        PM10: 10.5,
    },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const { datetime, ...valExcludeDate } = val;

    if (acc[val.datetime]) {
        acc[val.datetime] = { ...acc[val.datetime], ...valExcludeDate };
    } else {
        acc[val.datetime] = { ...valExcludeDate };
    }

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```